# What are the alternatives of pexpect in Clojure, Racket, Scala, and Common Lisp?

Tags: scala, clojure, terminal, racket, pexpect

I want a library to interact with CLI apps in these languages. 
(Is this off-topic in SO? If so, where do I post it?)

Comment: Why wouldn't one use the `expect` command directly?

Answer (score 2):

for Clojure the built in clojure.java.shell is a good option for calling expect directly  https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.java.shell/sh

Answer (score 1):

In Common Lisp, I'd use `uiop:launch-program`, which has the option of making stdin, stdout, and stderr streams available from the returned process-info.  Something like this:

```
(let ((ssh-process (uiop:launch-program (list* "ssh" hostname ssh-args)
                                       :input :stream
                                       :output :stream
                                       :error-output :stream)))
  (format (process-info-input ssh-process) "foo.sh a bar ~a" foo-arg)
  (frobnicate (read-line (process-info-output ssh-process))))
```

UIOP is shipped with ASDF, which is shipped with all modern implementations of Common Lisp.  Here is the README: https://gitlab.common-lisp.net/asdf/asdf/blob/master/uiop/README.md.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a list of alternatives in Wikipedia, but it doesn’t include one for any Lisps. :(

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expect

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't appear that there's an implementation of an expect-like library for Racket; you can certainly use `system` or `subprocess` to launch processes and interact with them using input & output ports.